# Database query returns an empty value

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, android-sqlite, sqflite

I make a query to the database and it gives an empty value, although there are at least two values in it (added via SQLite)

```
import 'package:connectify_app/model.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DB {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return null;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    String path = "Connectify.db";
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);
    return db;
  }

  _createDatabase(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL,password TEXT NOT NULL,city TEXT NOT NULL, bithday TEXT NOT NULL, hobbies TEXT)");
  }

  Future<List<ConnectifyModel>> getAllUsernames() async {
    await db;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> QueryResult =
        await _db!.rawQuery("SELECT username FROM users");
    return QueryResult.map((e) => ConnectifyModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

I've tried editing the query, but nothing worked